# required java.lang.String found org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

This is the code

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
List<NameValuePair>param=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token_type",tToken));
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token",acToken));

String json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS,"GET",param);
Log.d("JSON ",json);
```

This is the `tToken` and `acToken`

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("jsonToken"));
Log.d("Orders Response",obj.toString());

acToken= obj.getString("access_token");
tToken=obj.getString("token_type");
```

The problem is in the line `String json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS,"GET",param);`

It gives me this error 
`required java.lang.String found org.json.JSONObject`

i do understand the problem but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: maven thank you for the edit proposal , now i will know how to post my code on stackoverflow

Comment: use bold font only when they are needed .. else it will show *arrogance* ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` retuns a `JSONObject` and not a `String`. Change

```
 String json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS,"GET",param);
```

to

```
 JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ORDERS,"GET",param);
```

Comment: Sit thank you a lot i will acept your'e answer later(now i can't before it's to early, or so stack overflow system says)